# Getting an int instead of a float

Tags: c++, casting

I am doing something like this

```
int a = 3;
int b = 4;
float c = a/b ; //This returns 0 while its suppose to return 0.75
```

I wanted to know **why** the above code doesn't work ? I realize that 3 is an int and 4 is an int too. However the result is a float which is being assigned to float. However I am getting a 0 here. Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: HINT: the result from integer division is integer. The result of the division is then assigned to a float. That is `a/b` results in an `int`. Cast that however you want, but you aren't gonna get 0.75 out of it.

Comment: Can you put that down as answer

Comment: Compiler doesn't look that far ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float c = a/b ;
```

`a` and `b` are integers, so it is integer division.

From the C++ standard:

> **5.6 Multiplicative operators [expr.mul]**
>
> For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.

Instaed, try this:

```
float c = a / static_cast<float>(b);
```

(As **@TrevorHickey** suggested, `static_cast<float>` is better than old-style `(float)` cast.)

Comment: Could you tell me why you converted b to float ?

Comment: If either a or b is a float, the result will be a float.  Also look into static_cast as it is better practice in c++

Comment: @TrevorHickey Did you mean static_cast? (First, I classified the question as C-related. That's why old style :))

Comment: @MistyD It is basically a set of most complex to least complex [precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The division is evaluated first, and because it is two integer operands, it evaluates to an integer... which then only get assigned to a float.

This is due to a [predefined set of rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09ka8bxx.aspx) that decreases in type complexity. To force the result to be of a particular type (at least), at least one of the operands needs to be of that type. (via a `static_cast< >` )

Thus:

```
float c = a / static_cast<float>(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant divide two ints and receive a float. You either have to cast to a float or have the types as a float.

```
float a = 3;
float b = 4;
float c = a/b;
```

or

```
float c = (float)a/(float)b;
```

Answer (score 0):

HINT: the result from integer division is integer. The result of the division is then assigned to a float. That is a/b results in an int. Cast that however you want, but you aren't gonna get 0.75 out of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in C++, you should use the static_cast method over the implicit cast.
This will ensure that the type can be safely cast at compile time.

```
float c = a/static_cast<float>(b);
```